# adb command for launching an app with security exception

Tags: android, adb

When launching an app using adb command "am start intent.... ", I got an security exception stating that "java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial:", and the app doesn't get launched.

When I checked StackOverflow for solutions, I found solutions which are based on editing the manifest.xml file. I dont have any permissions to edit the file. Since am a user of that app and not a developer.

My questions are 
1. Is there any way to escape this exception via adb commands. I need to escape this through commands, because its a third party app also I don't have access to manifest.xml file.

1. Else is there any other way to launch the app through adb command??

Comment: What's your device? Did you enable "Third party apps"? Did you click "Trust this computer" or similar on your device?

Answer (score 0):

If you root your device you can gain root access/permissions by using `su` before your commands. This should prevent you from being denied due to permissions.

Comment: Thanks Mark for your answer. But I am looking for a ADB command. Since I don't have the permission for Rooting the device.